# Set the sequence of execution of asynchronous dispatch (redux\redux-saga)

Tags: async-await, react-redux, redux-saga

I need to perform an asynchronous request. To do this, I'm debating a preloader, then I make a request, then I want to stop the preloader. The console should have: "show loader, load-app, hide loader", and output "show loader, hide loader, loading-app". How to save a sequence of calls?
How set the sequence of execution of asynchronous dispatch (redux\redux-saga)?

```
import { showLoader, hideLoader } from '../../reducer1'
import { authorizeToken } from '../reducer2'
async componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    const tokenLS = localStorage.getItem('token')

        await dispatch(showLoader()); //show loader
        await dispatch(authorizeToken(tokenLS)); // async request
        await dispatch(hideLoader()); //hide loader
    }
}
```

This code for Loader

```
import * as act from './actions'

const initialState = {
    loadingPage: false
}

export const showLoader = () => {
    console.log('show loader')
    document.body.classList.add('loading-app')
    return { type: act.startLoading }
}

export const hideLoader = () => {
    console.log('hide loader')
    document.body.classList.remove('loading-app')
    return { type: act.finishLoading }
}

export default function loading(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case act.startLoading:
            return { ...state, loadingPage: true }
        case act.finishLoading:
            return { ...state, loadingPage: false }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

This code for async request:

```
function* authorizeWithToken({ payload: { token } }) {

    try {

        const { token:userToken } = yield call(authApi.authUserFromToken, token)
        yield put({ type: AUTH_SUCCESS, payload: { token: userToken } })
        yield console.log('end request')

    } catch (error) {
        throw new  Error(`error request with token ${token}`)
    }
}

export function* authorizeSaga() {
    yield takeLatest(AUTH_REQUEST, authorize)
}

export function* authorizeWithTokenSaga() {
    yield takeLatest(AUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN, authorizeWithToken)
}
```

This is reducer:

```
export const authorizeToken = (token) => ({
    type: AUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN,
    payload: {token}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some misunderstanding here.  Your `componentDidMount` function does not need to by async.  `redux-saga` enables you to move all async actions into sagas and out of the components.  That way your components are easier to manage.  I would change your `componentDidMount` to dispatch a single action and let your saga handle all the logic.  Try changing it to this:

```
import { authorizeToken } from '../reducer2'

componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    const tokenLS = localStorage.getItem('token')
    dispatch(authorizeToken(tokenLS)); // async request
}
```

Now in your saga, try this:

```
import { showLoader, hideLoader } from '../../reducer1'

function* authorizeWithToken({ payload: { token } }) {

    try {
        yield put(showLoader());
        const { token:userToken } = yield call(authApi.authUserFromToken, token)
        yield put({ type: AUTH_SUCCESS, payload: { token: userToken } })
        yield put(hideLoader())
    } catch (error) {
        throw new  Error(`error request with token ${token}`)
    }
}
```

Now your saga will be in charge of displaying the loader, fetching the data, and hiding the loader.  In that order.